# date format not recognized when converting to timestamp from timezone

Tags: oracle11g, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

What's wrong with below statement. I am getting error 
`date format not recognized`

`select to_timestamp_tz( to_char(to_date(sysdate-1,'dd/mon/yyyy') ,'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss  -05:30'),'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss TZH:TZM') from dual`

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert sysdate-1 to date. Its already a date. So your query should be something like:

```
       select to_timestamp_tz( to_char(sysdate-1 ,'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss'),'dd/mon/yyyy hh:mi:ss TZH:TZM') from dual;
```

Hope it helps

Vishad

Comment: Thanks Vishad for your reply but I need to add the timezone in the query itself, How can I achieve this

Comment: @Siva: Can you please elaborate a bit on that, like provide your desired output and what is the logic that you are trying to implement.
Thanks

Comment: In my question I have used `-5:30` in query itself but in your provided answer query returns timezone but I need to use timezone in query and return in result aswell, Can you please guide me inthat way. Thanks